# Share marks in vim across machines

Tags: vim

I use a few different machines and I was wondering if there was a way to store or share marks in files that are opened on the different machines.

If so, how could this be done? I am fine saving/re-storing a helper file in the `.vim` directory if that is necessary to do the above.

This would be for both `lowercase` and `uppercase` marks. I suppose one option would be to put the `.viminfo` in a git repository and share that between machines, but I'm wondering what unintended consequences that might have. Currently I have:

```
set viminfo='100,f1,n~/.vim/viminfo
```

Note that I'm not interested in storing it [across sessions on the same machine](https://vimhelp.org/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-17.3), but different computers (one local one in aws).

Comment: Lowercase marks are never auto-saved.

Comment: @Matt -- does it save with the `'100` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice is to use a separate session-like file that only stores marks. The command [`:wviminfo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:wviminfo) can write a separate file. So the plan is: save `&viminfo` and clear it, write a file with marks, restore `&viminfo`.

```
function! SaveMarks()
    let save_vim = &viminfo " Save viminfo
    set &viminfo='100,:0,/0,<0,@0 " Clear viminfo - store only file marks for 100 files
    wviminfo! marks.vim
    let &viminfo = save_vim " Restore viminfo
endfunction
```

Copy the file to the other host, read it using [`:rviminfo`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#:rviminfo):

```
:rviminfo! marks.vim
```